# Creating a limited use version of a program in VC++

Tags: c++, programming-languages

Our company helps migrate client software from other languages to C++.  We provide them C++ source code for their application along with header files and compiled libraries for runtime support functions.  We charge for both the migration as well as the runtime.  Recently a potential client asked to migrate one of a number of systems they have.  This system contains 7 programs and we would like to limit the runtime so only these 7 programs can acess it.  We can time limit the runtime by putting an encrypted expiration date in the object library but, since we have to provide the source code for the converted programs, we are having difficult coming up with a way to limit the access to a specific set of programs. Obviously, anything we put into the source code to identify the program could be copied to any other program so the only hope seems to be having the run time library discover some set of characteristics about the programs and then validating them against a set of characteristics embedded in the run time library.  As I understand it, C++ has very little reflection capability (RTTI is all I could find) so I wanted to ask if anyone has faced a similar problem and found a way to solve it.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Based on the two answers a little clarification seems in order.  We fully expect the client to modify the source code and normally we provide them an unrestricted version of the runtime libraries.  This particular client requested a version that was limited to a single system and is happy to enter into a license that restricts the use of the runtime library to that system.  Therefore a discussion of the legal issues isn't relevant.  The issue is a technical one -- given a license that is limited to a single system and given that the client has the source to the calling programs but not the runtime, is there a way to limit access to the runtime to the set of programs comprising that system thus enforcing the terms of the license.

Comment: How about making a registry entry everytime it is run?

Comment: The registry is an interesting idea for Windows but I'm not quite sure how that would work.  When one of these programs first calls the runtime, the runtime needs to verify that the caller is an authorized program.  What would you suggest storing in the registry to do that?

Comment: @William: Based on my limited knowledge of how your runtime library works, after verifying that the program is authorized, I would check a program-defined registry entry probably created in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and see if the count is over a certain number. If it is not, then you increment a UsageCounter. Anything you implement though will be broken if someone is smart enough.

Comment: I agree that storing a UsageCounter in the registry will provide some control.  The real issue is the "after verifying that the program is authorzied" part.  Since the user has the source code to the program but only the object code to the runtime library the challenge I am seeking ideas for is how to do that verification.

Comment: @William: What I fail to understand is the difference between the source and the runtime library. Which needs to be checked?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, there are a set of 7 programs that are allowed to access the runtime.  The runtime needs to verify that it is being called by one of these programs only.  Since it is provided in object form we can embed checks in it.  Since the program is provided in source code we can't. I had originally hoped I could use reflection but C++ doesn't seem to have a lot of that.

Comment: @William: Can all 7 access it or only one at a time? If the source is available, then it's game over.

Answer (score 1):

If they're not supposed to make further changes to the programs, why did you give them the source code?  And if they are expected to continue changing the programs (i.e. maintenance), who decides whether a change constitutes a new program that's not allowed to use the library?

There's no technical way to enforce that licensing model.

There's possibly a legal way -- in the code that loads/enables the library, write a comment "This is a copy protection measure".  Then DMCA forbids them from including that code into other programs (in the USA).  But IANAL, and I don't think DMCA is valid anyway.

Consult a lawyer to find out what rights you have under the contract/bill of sale to restrict their use.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer I could think of is to get the name and/or path of the calling process-- simply compare this name to the 7 "allowed" programs in your support library.  Certainly, they could create a new process with the same name, but they might not know to do so.

Another level could be to further compare the executable size against the known size for that application.  (You'll likely want to allow a reasonably wide range around the expected size, in case they make changes to the source code, and/or compile with different options.)

As another thought, you might try adding some seemingly benign strings into the app's resources.  ("Copyright 2011 ~Your Corporation Name~")-- You can then scan the parent executable for the magic strings.  If they create a new product, they might not think to create this resource.

Finally, as already noted by Ben, if you are giving them the source code, there are likely no foolproof solutions to this problem.  (As he said, at what point does "modified" code become a new application?)  The best you will likely be able to do is to add enough small roadblocks that they won't bother trying to use that lib for another product.  It likely depends on how determined and/or lucky they are.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just technically limit the use of the runtime to one system? There are many software protection solutions out there, one that comes to my mind is [SmartDongle](http://www.smartdongle.com/).

Now the runtime could still be used by any other program on that machine, but I think this should be a minor concern, no?

Comment: I think we may have an ambiguous reference to the word 'system.'  I was using the term not refer to a hardware system (a machine) but to an aggregation of several application programs that together constitute a software system (like order entry or payroll).  The software system could theoretically run on a different hardware system each time it is run.  Sorry for the confusion.